# Parsing specific HTML tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, tags, html-parsing

I'm looking for the Javascript to parse the following HTML:

```
<p>random text random text random text random text</p>
<kbd><h2>Heading One</h2>Body text Body text Body text Body text</kbd>
<p>random text random text random text random text</p>
```

... and return just:

```
Heading One
```

In other words, I'd like to strip all tags and Body Text from within the `<kbd>` tags.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you want a pure javascript solution or a jQuery (or other similar library) whould be enought?

Comment: Your desired output does not match what you say you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = /* that HTML string here */;
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = input;

var h2 = div.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
var text = h2.innerText || h2.textContent;

alert(text); // alerts "Heading One"
```

#### Reference:

- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)
- [`element.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.textContent) ([Quirksmode compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04))

#### Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/vaVPF/

Answer (score 2):

Regex?

```
var s = "<p>random text</p>\n" +
  "<kbd><h2>Heading One</h2>Body text</kbd>\n" +
  "<p>random text</p>";

s.match(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/)[1] // == "Heading One"
```

This matches group one as the shortest possible `(.*?)` string between `<h2>...</h2>`.

You can find all matches using the `g` option.

```
s.match(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/g) // == ["<h2>Heading One</h2>"]
```

Note that groups are not accessible.

For multiline content between tags, use

```
s.match(/<tag>[\s\S]*?<\/tag>/ig)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you include jquery ([jquery.com](http://jquery.com)) you can do this:

```
var heading=$("h2").html();
```

Comment: That only works if the HTML to be parsed is somewhere in the page already.