# How to remove whole HTML, HEAD tags and BODY tag from string with HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a template file that is called myWebsite.html. It contains everything that HTML template needs to have. So it has HTML, HEAD and BODY tags. I want to load it with JavaScript and put into one of divs on the site. So i don't want to have the HTML, HEAD and BODY tags. How to do this?

This is a prototype of what i need to have:

```
$val = getData('myWebsite.html');
$val = removeHTMLHEADBODYTAGS($val); //remove these tags with everything insite, also remove the body tag but leave the contents in the body tag. Also remove the end tags of body and html - HOW TO DO THIS?
div.innerHTML = $val;
```

I want to do this in pure JavaScript = NO jQUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract it with a regex. Something like: `/\<body[^>]*\>(.*)\<\/body/m` - that should return all content within the `<BODY>` element.

```
$val = getData('myWebsite.html');
var reg = /\<body[^>]*\>([^]*)\<\/body/m;
div.innerHTML = $val.match( reg )[1];
```

Example jsFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/x4hPZ/1/

Comment: hm - CR LF is the line ending I used. And I don't see any issues either in that jsFiddle code you posted. (I'm on Win7 Firefox10) What are you using? I thought that the m flag in the regex would take care of any line endings...

Comment: Ok - found this article: http://siphon9.net/loune/2011/02/match-any-character-including-new-line-in-javascript-regexp/ Made changes to the code snipped based on that: http://jsfiddle.net/czg88/2/ Does that work better? Since I can't reproduce the issue I can't confirm myself.

Comment: One thing: it should be ( reg )[1] so to get the contents of body. Thanks!

Comment: Ah - yes. Silly mistake on my part. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

Why not fetch the information out of the  tag and then work with that? There is no need to fetch all information and the removing html, head and body:

```
content = $val.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML();
```

Comment: +Hidde Right. It would be great solution but how to be able to call getElementsByTagName if val is string?

Comment: This is possible by converting the val string to a dom element with new Element. I have made a small example here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TwVbU/)

Comment: +Hidde It uses MooTools. So it's not the solution i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
var bodyContents = htmlstring.split('<body');//no >, body could have a property
bodyContents = bodyContents[1].replace('</body>','').replace('</html>','').replace(/^.*\>/,'');
```

The last regex replace removes the closing `>` of the opening body tag, and all possible tag properties.

This is, however, not the way I would do things... If at all possible, I'd create an (i)Frame node, load the html into that frame, and get the innerHTML from the body tag. Just a suggestion.

Right, the iFrame way:

```
var document.ifrm = document.createElement('iframe')
document.ifrm.style = 'visibility:hidden';
document.body.appendChild(document.ifrm);
idoc = (document.ifrm.contentDocument ? document.ifrm.contentDocument : document.ifrm.contentWindow.document;)
idoc.open();
idoc.writeln('<html><head><title>foobar</title></head><body><p>Content</p></body></html>');
idoc.close();
var bodyContents = idoc.body.innerHTML;
```

For code explanation: http://softwareas.com/injecting-html-into-an-iframe

or any other hit on google.com for that matter :)

Comment: Hm... it's sounds like a solution but... will bodyContents after first line not be a array? And further more... about the iFrame... i just don't like this kind of solutions. It's somehow messy.

Comment: you're right, sorry... the second line should read `bodyContents[1] = bodyContents[1].replace(...`.
I don't know why you feel the solution of using a temp frame is messy. Creating a frame, without appending it to the current document, parses the html, and giving you all the methods JS has to offer to extract the pieces you need. You can even manipulate/check the data before using it in your site. Seems to me to be an even better solution, actually. However, as I said, it was just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var your_content = $("html").clone().find("head,body").remove().end().html();
});
```

1. get the content with "html" selector
2. make a copy with `clone`
3. `find` the tags you want to remove
4. remove them and
5. convert back to HTML

all in one line.

HTH,

--hennson

Comment: ...or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869393/parsing-specific-html-tags-in-javascript if you would like to work without a framework...